# What is the lifespan of a Bitrise build artifact?

Tags: bitrise

The [Bitrise guide on artifacts](https://devcenter.bitrise.io/builds/build-artifacts-online/) doesn't specify how long they will be accessible in the build. Are they permanent, or will they expire after a certain amount of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From discuss.bitrise.io https://discuss.bitrise.io/t/availability-of-builds-and-artifacts-on-bitrise-for-how-long-artifacts-are-kept/984

> Right now we don’t have a hard limit, you can store unlimited builds & build artifacts. Of course, if someone abuses the system we’ll contact them, but for normal use it’s “unlimited”.
>
> We might introduce some kind of limit in the future, but we don’t have any plans for that right now.

Answer (score 0):

I've currently got a support ticket open for it so it might be a bug, but a download attempt for a 6 month old build artifact failed on me with a raw Amazon S3 warning about storage tiers.